# as2: Stop Movieclip within a movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I have a movieclip called "main", inside of that I have all my layers and tweens, within another movieClip in those layers I have yet another movieClip which I wish to stop playing when the second movie clip has played 3 times.

movieClips:
main > trampoline > boyBounce

I have to code to stop the second "main" MC, but not the "boyBounce" one.

When the "main" MC have played 3 times It calls commands to gotoAndStop, I need a command I can call to stop/or goto the first frame of "boyBounce".

Ive tried:

```
_root.boyBounce.gotoAndStop("bounce_stop");
boyBounce.stop();
_level0.boyBounce.gotoAndStop("bounce_stop");
```

"bounce_stop" is the name of the first frame in "boyBounce".

Cheers

EDIT: I'll settle for a command that will stop ALL movieClips playing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the `boyBounce` movie at the first frame. this code helps you

```
_root.main.trampoline.boyBounce.gotoAndStop("bounce_stop");
```

Or, if you want to stop the `trampoline` movie at any of the desired frame then this one helps you

```
 _root.main.trampoline.gotoAndStop(FRAME_NUMBER);
```

Or, if you want to simply stop the animation of `trampoline` then

```
_root.main.trampoline.stop();
```

or `boyBounce`

```
_root.main.trampoline.boyBounce.stop();
```

BTW, you can trace the thing which doesn't works in the correct direction. For example, in your code if you are trying to `trace` `_root.boyBounce` or `boyBounce` or `_level0.boyBounce` it logs `null`. Because there is no movie with the name `boyBounce` in the stage. Take care on object scope.

FYI, If you want to access any movieclip from the stage you should access via it's parent, you can't access the child directly unless you are accessing from the same level.

Always remember to access like `PARENT_NAME.PARENT_NAME.CHILD_NAME`. Also don't forget if you don't add `_root` in the front then it's start from the level you have ur code and it searches the movie with name `PARENT_NAME` in that level and returns null if there is no movie in that name.

Comment: Trying out the first one I get the following error: Access of undefined property _root. And the animation does not stop. When accessing MCs are you meaning "Instance Names" or something else?

Comment: I meant instance name of the movieclips

Comment: Have u check the instance names and try to trace the value before that line?